# Does $x^5+4x+2=0$ have a solution in matrices with rational coefficients?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, polynomials, galois-theory

$x^5+4x+5=0$ has Galois group $A_5$, so its Complex roots are not expressible in terms of ordinary radicals.

Is there a solution in matrices with rational coefficients? If so I suspect they may be $60 \times 60$ matrices and how easy are they to construct?

Comment: Do you mean an element $A \in M_{60}(\mathbb{Q})$ such that $A^5 + 4A + 5=0$? If so, why would you expect such a matrix to exist?

Comment: I do not know whether they exist or not. What I do know is that it is easy to construct rational matrices for ordinary radicals, e.g. $((0, 1),(-3, 0))$ for $sqrt(-3)$. Matrices can be used to model groups, including permutation groups related to zeros of polynomials. So is there some way of putting it together?

Comment: Look up "companion matrix".

Comment: Thanks @ChrisGodsil - that works. A simple $5 \times 5$ matrix suffices.

Comment: @GeorgeChauvet If you've solved your problem using Chris Godsil's suggestion, please consider writing an answer to your question.

Comment: The companion matrix gives you just one root, but the algehra it generates is not the splitting field since thiis algebra has only dimension 5 exist. But there is a way to construct the other roots as 60 x 60 matrices.